# Zend Framework Caching in memory

Tags: zend-framework, zend-cache

is there any way to cache results from Zend DB in memory using Zend Framework (version 1.8) ?
Or should I use server side solutions to implement "cache in memory per process"?

So can you share best practices completing such issues?

Comment: What I found while making some investigation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792075/in-memory-script-cache-backend-in-zend-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached for caching into Memcache server which holds cache in memory